# NSIS:Create shortcut doesn't work in windows 8

Tags: installation, nsis

I am using NSIS to create my application.It is working fine in windows xp,vista and windows 7.
but in windows 8 shortcut of my application in desktop is not creating.But in other OS it's creating shortcut in desktop properly.Why does it doesnt create shortcut in windows 8 OS?Is there any solution to solve this?

Comment: Please post some example code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `RequestExecutionLevel` in your script? If not there could be a Windows compatibility shim getting in your way...